# Formatting of a webpage is affected

Tags: firefox

I am not sure how to explain this issue. I am using firefox 3.6.4 on windows7. Formatting of sites: stackoverflow family sites and codeproject (only these sites) is being affected. I mean I see basic text, url with no bgcolor. I am not sure what is going on here. If I do a cleanup, the sites work fine till I login again and everything goes awry. Disabling all my add ons or switching to a default theme has no effect. MY problem is same as this : http://www.techsupportforum.com/alternative-computing/mozilla-firefox-browsers/106691-problems-firefox-formatting.html

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas:

- Go to the View menu, Page Style, and make sure "Basic Page Style" is selected (and not "No Style"). Or try changing it, then changing it back to "Basic Page Style".
- Try another web browser and see if it has the same problems. If so, there might be possible problems with a firewall, security settings, a proxy server or other filter. If another web browser works correctly, that suggests the problem is with some setting, add-on, or other bug in Firefox.
- Try loading the style sheets below and see if the style sheet code appears (working correctly) or if you get an error message or a long loading time (possible problems).

  [Super User style sheet](http://sstatic.net/su/all.css?v=609fabe2825d)
  [Stack Overflow style sheet](http://sstatic.net/so/all.css?v=4864b39b46cf)
  [Code Project sytle sheet](http://s.codeproject.com/App_Themes/Std/CSS/CodeProject.css?dt=2.3.0025)
  [Code Project tabs style sheet](http://s.codeproject.com/App_Themes/Std/CSS/tabs.css)

  If you get an error message or long loading times, perhaps a firewall or security setting is blocking the style sheets.

  If the style sheets load correctly on their own, maybe something is blocking the style sheet link on the normal page because it's a different domain name than the main page. Or maybe because it has a ? in the URL. These are very wild guesses, but I noticed the sites you're having problems with have style sheet URLs like that. If you notice other sites that aren't working we might find their style sheets have something else in common.